# How to run a command line script through a normal Zend Framework application

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line

I am working on a ZF application that needs to run a command line script and then parse the results into something meaningful and return to the user.

I know there are various PHP functions, like `exec` and `system`, but I was wondering if there is anything built into Zend Framework that does command line scripting easily.

Even if there isn't a ZF specific function, what is the best function/method to use for running a command line script and then retrieving the results in PHP upon completion of the script.

Comment: `exec` would do fine. No additional overhead needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a Service which uses `exec` to get what you need. You can add some basic error handling there.

Answer (score 0):

You can start an process under linux with this:

[ZendX_Console_Process_Unix](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.console.process.unix.overview.html)

But never tryed it..

Comment: When I looked at that, it appeared to be for when you are running via CLI to start with, but I am running the application normally via HTTP. Also note, I need the output back - which I don't think that does either.

Answer (score 0):

We recently needed to do this (we use ZF too), hope this helps: http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/how-to-run-a-php-script-from-command-line/